# Convert Yearly data into quarterly data with specific rules

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, date-conversion

I am working with SQL and need to convert data that is available yearly into quarterly data, but with some specific rules. For example, in the source data I have one record for the year of 2020, I need this to be converted to be 4 records for 2022Q3, 2022Q4, 2023Q1, 2023Q2. For the prior year of 2019, I need 4 records for 2021Q3, 2021Q4, 2022Q1, 2022Q2. And so forth.

Actual data

| year | FIPS | PercentagePopulation | NumberOfPeople |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 |
| 2020 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 |

Expected result

| YearQtr | FIPS | PercentagePopulation | NumberOfPeople |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021Q3 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 |
| 2021Q4 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 |
| 2022Q1 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 |
| 2022Q2 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 |
| 2022Q3 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 |
| 2022Q4 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 |
| 2023Q1 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 |
| 2023Q2 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 |

Comment: Please edit your question to 1) properly tag the variant of SQL you're using and 2) show what you've done some far, along with issue(s) you're having. Currently this is just some data and a requirement. Also: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What if there are more than one record in a year ?

Comment: There won't be; it is annual data we receive, one record per county in the USA. I just need to apply the values for a certain year for a set of 4 quarters that are in a future fiscal year (July 1 - June 30).

Answer (score 1):

Work with this, you can add any number of years and concatenate year and quarter

https://dbfiddle.uk/4N2MkZ-0

```
CREATE TABLE population (
    year INT,
    FIPS INT,
    PercentagePopulation VARCHAR(10),
    NumberOfPeople INT
);

INSERT INTO population (year, FIPS, PercentagePopulation, NumberOfPeople)
VALUES (2019, 45001, '11.40%', 90000),
       (2020, 45001, '12.10%', 100000);

SELECT p.year, q.quarter, p.FIPS, p.NumberOfPeople  NumberOfPeople, p.PercentagePopulation
  ,str(p.year+1)+'Q'+trim(str(q.quarter)) as inventedPeriod
FROM population p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS quarter, 3 as position UNION SELECT 2,4 UNION SELECT 3,1 UNION SELECT 4,2) q
ORDER BY year, q.position;
```

| year | quarter | FIPS | NumberOfPeople | PercentagePopulation | inventedPeriod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 3 | 45001 | 90000 | 11.40% | 2020Q3 |
| 2019 | 4 | 45001 | 90000 | 11.40% | 2020Q4 |
| 2019 | 1 | 45001 | 90000 | 11.40% | 2020Q1 |
| 2019 | 2 | 45001 | 90000 | 11.40% | 2020Q2 |
| 2020 | 3 | 45001 | 100000 | 12.10% | 2021Q3 |
| 2020 | 4 | 45001 | 100000 | 12.10% | 2021Q4 |
| 2020 | 1 | 45001 | 100000 | 12.10% | 2021Q1 |
| 2020 | 2 | 45001 | 100000 | 12.10% | 2021Q2 |

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions that are just requirements with no effort. Further: the OP hasn't specified which database engine they're using. And lastly... [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Haha, yes @Horaxius thank you thank you!! It isn't quite working yet but I can see the logic you are working with so I'm fiddling with the cross join possibility. I updated the quarters I need above, they got altered somehow. It's kind of an odd conversion I need to do where the year 2020 is used for 2022Q3, 2022Q4, 2023Q1, and 2023Q2.

Comment: @d4e_1992 have you seen the change to set the order as you needed?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `INNER JOIN` to join every row with all rows produced by `UNNEST` :

`GENERATE_ARRAY` used here to generate two years values based on the selected year so 2019 would be 2021 and 2022.

```
WITH  cte AS 
(
    SELECT '2019' AS year , 45001  AS FIPS, '11.40%' AS PercentagePopulation, 90000 AS NumberOfPeople 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2020' AS year , 45001  AS FIPS, '12.10%' AS PercentagePopulation, 100000 AS NumberOfPeople 
),
cte2 as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by year ) as rn
    FROM cte
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(cast(year as int)+2,cast(year as int)+3)) AS YearQtr
)
select CONCAT(YearQtr, quarter) as YearQtr, FIPS, PercentagePopulation, NumberOfPeople, year
from cte2
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(['Q3', 'Q4']) as quarter
where rn = 1
UNION ALL
select CONCAT(YearQtr, quarter) as YearQtr, FIPS, PercentagePopulation, NumberOfPeople, year
from cte2
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(['Q1', 'Q2']) as quarter
where rn = 2
ORDER BY year
```

Result :

| YearQtr | FIPS | PercentagePopulation | NumberOfPeople | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021Q3 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 | 2019 |
| 2021Q4 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 | 2019 |
| 2022Q1 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 | 2019 |
| 2022Q2 | 45001 | 11.40% | 90000 | 2019 |
| 2022Q3 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 | 2020 |
| 2022Q4 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 | 2020 |
| 2023Q1 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 | 2020 |
| 2023Q2 | 45001 | 12.10% | 100000 | 2020 |